# WPF - How to align treeviewitems in a treeview so that they align with the columns?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-interface, treeview

I'm trying to get the child tree view items so that they align with the column header, regardless of the size of the previous columns. I want to avoid using a predefined margin space as it messes up with the resizing of certain elements.

Here's a picture to better illustrate what I want:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvrLS.jpg)

Here's my tree view xaml:

```
<!-- TreeGrid "Control" -->
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

    <!-- Resources -->
    <Border.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TreeViewItem}}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"
                        MinWidth="19" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ClickMode="Press" Name="Expander">
                                    <ToggleButton.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
                                            <Setter Property="UIElement.Focusable" Value="false" />
                                            <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Width" Value="16" />
                                            <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Height" Value="16" />
                                            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                                                        <Border Padding="5,5,5,5" Background="#00FFFFFF" Width="16" Height="16">
                                                            <Path Fill="#00FFFFFF" Stroke="#FF989898" Name="ExpandPath">
                                                                <Path.Data>
                                                                    <PathGeometry Figures="M0,0L0,6L6,0z" />
                                                                </Path.Data>
                                                                <Path.RenderTransform>
                                                                    <RotateTransform Angle="135"  CenterX="3" CenterY="3" />
                                                                </Path.RenderTransform>
                                                            </Path>
                                                        </Border>
                                                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                            <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                                                <Setter TargetName="ExpandPath" Property="Shape.Stroke" Value="#FF1BBBFA" />
                                                                <Setter TargetName="ExpandPath" Property="Shape.Fill" Value="#00FFFFFF" />
                                                            </Trigger>
                                                            <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True">
                                                                <Setter TargetName="ExpandPath" Property="UIElement.RenderTransform">
                                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                                        <RotateTransform Angle="180" CenterX="3" CenterY="3" />
                                                                    </Setter.Value>
                                                                </Setter>
                                                                <Setter TargetName="ExpandPath" Property="Shape.Fill" Value="#FF595959" />
                                                                <Setter TargetName="ExpandPath" Property="Shape.Stroke" Value="#FF262626" />
                                                            </Trigger>
                                                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                        </Style>
                                    </ToggleButton.Style>
                                </ToggleButton>
                                <Border x:Name="Bd"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}"
                                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}"
                                            Padding="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}"
                                            Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}"
                                            SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                                            Grid.Column="1">
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Header"
                                    Content="{TemplateBinding HeaderedContentControl.Header}"
                                    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderedContentControl.HeaderTemplate}"
                                    ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderedItemsControl.HeaderStringFormat}"
                                    ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding HeaderedItemsControl.HeaderTemplateSelector}"
                                    ContentSource="Header"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                                </Border>
                                <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Grid.Row="1" />
                            </Grid>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="TreeViewItem.IsExpanded" Value="False">
                                <Setter TargetName="ItemsHost" Property="UIElement.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.HasItems"  Value="False">
                                <Setter TargetName="Expander" Property="UIElement.Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="TreeViewItem.IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Panel.Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" />
                                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="TreeViewItem.IsSelected" Value="True" />
                                    <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="False" />
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Panel.Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" />
                                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" />
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>


        <Style x:Key="TextBlockStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <!--<Setter Property="Margin" Value="3 0 3 0"/>-->
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="TextBlockBoldStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" BasedOn="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}">
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        </Style>
    </Border.Resources>

    <!-- Content -->
    <Grid Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- Column headers -->
        <TreeViewItem Grid.Row="0" BorderThickness="1">
            <TreeViewItem.Header>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.4*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.4*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Name" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockBoldStyle}"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Status" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockBoldStyle}"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="Files" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockBoldStyle}"/>
                </Grid>
            </TreeViewItem.Header>
        </TreeViewItem>

        <!-- Data rows -->
        <TreeView x:Name="MainTreeView" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding SubItems}" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="0 1 0 0">
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                
                <!-- Level 0 template leaves space for 2 child "Toggle" levels -->
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding SubItems}">
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.4*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.4*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding StatusMsg}" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding FilesMsg}" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}"/>
                    </Grid>

                    <!-- Level 1 template leaves space for 1 child "Toggle" level -->
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding SubItems}">
                            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.4*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.4*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}"/>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding StatusMsg}" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}"/>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding FilesMsg}" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

I tried using a custom style that horizontally stretches the elements, but that still didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using this library: https://github.com/Anapher/MetroTreeListView, and changed some things to make it work in my project.

Here's the final result: [final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDI8P.png)